# Cokernel and Mapping Cone in Grothendieck Group

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, derived-categories

I suppose this question is very easy, but at the moment I cannot find a rigorous answer.

Imagine there is an adjunction of exact functors $F:\mathcal C\stackrel{\dashv}{\longleftrightarrow} \mathcal D:G$, which has a natural transformation $\eta: 1\Rightarrow GF$ as adjunction unit. Now consider its cokernel $C=\operatorname{coker}(\eta): \mathcal C\rightarrow \mathcal C$. I want to know what is its action in the Grothendieck group $K_0(\mathcal C)$ but I cannot assume $C$ to be left-exact.

I can pass to the derived category $D^b(\mathcal C)$, where I can find a triangle $M\rightarrow GFM\rightarrow K\rightarrow$. Since I know an expression for $[GFM]\in K_0(\mathcal C)$, I can deduce what $[K]$ is.

My question: Is there any reason why $[K]$ should be actually $[CM]$?

Or: Are the the left derived functor of a cokernel of a nat. trafo and the mapping cones of the associated maps related in some way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If we let $F$ and $G$ be the $0$ functors (that is $F$ and $G$ maps everything to 0). The adjunction unit is obviously the morphism $M\rightarrow 0=GF(M)$ so its cokernel is 0 and its action on $K_0(C)$ is also 0. But in the derived category, we have a triangle $M\rightarrow 0\rightarrow M[1]\rightarrow $, so the action on $K_0$ is $[M]\mapsto -[M]$.

Comment: Okay, I see this is not a good sign for a satisfactory relation between these two classes in $K_0$. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What I found today which brings much more light into the topic (at least for me): The cokernel of morphisms in  is a functor $\mathcal C^{[1]}\rightarrow \mathcal C$, whose derived functor is the mapping cone $D(\mathcal C^{[1]})\rightarrow D(\mathcal C)$. Since $\eta: \mathcal C\rightarrow \mathcal C^{[1]}$ induces $D(\mathcal C)\rightarrow D(\mathcal C^{[1]})$, which yields an endofuctor cone() of *D*().

Comment: Just curious: what's the source for this?

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ: This script: http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~mgroth/monos.htmpl